# Convert 2D to 2D matrix with different dimension

Tags: matlab

I loaded an image in Matlab which has properties:

```
 Name(X)   , Size (512x512)  , Bytes (262144)  , Class(uint8) ,
```

I added gaussian noise and remove that noise by using wavelet transform. By doing Inverse wavelet transform I get the final output image:

```
Name(Xsyn) , Size (504x504)  , Bytes (2032128) , Class(Double)
```

Now I am trying to calculate the signal-to-noise ratio (SNR) by using

```
SNR = 20*log10(norm(X(:))/norm(X(:)-Xsyn(:)));
```

But it show the following error:

```
??? Error using ==> minus
Matrix dimensions must agree.
```

So I think I should change my matrix dimension of the final image (`Xsyn`). Now how can I change this matrix dimension of image `Xsyn` (504x504 ) to `Xsyn` size (512x512)?

Or is there another way to find out the SNR?

Comment: you need to be more specific. What was the wavelet transform you used?

Comment: I used db2 , Now can you answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the function you use doesn't have a handle that keeps the original size of the matrix (for instance conv2 has the option to output the same size using (`conv2(Image,filer,'same')`) , you can always do this quick and dirty fix:

```
 X=imresize(X,size(Xsyn));
```

and the rest will follow...

Comment: Could u please give some explanation about conv2(Image,filer,'same'),
I mean where to use it, Image=X?? filter=??

Comment: I think it is better you'll add some code you wrote to see what you used. Maybe conv2 is irrelevant in your case.

Comment: I din not use con2 function, when I just used just this X=imresize(X,size(Xsyn));, then SNR is showing ! I am soooo happyyy.......thanks.......

Comment: Today is my first day at http://stackoverflow.com ..... so trying to understand it